# Overlay above the map

Tags: android

I am creating an app registering it goes to a map where it has a map and drawer activity with it. As we click the register button should show the map activity withe drawer and have to overlay an image above it with 4 buttons. I am hereby attaching the screenshot here

[image: Screenshot of the image]

Comment: Where is the screenshot ? You just missed it.

Comment: @Piyush oh god. how can i add now?

Comment: In `Body` there is the `6th` number of Gallery icon. Just click it and drop your screenshot there.

Comment: @Piyush can i paste a google drive link in this comment? and can u check it?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tGTyu2WkQIN2WcTlaEWZwemCUFko62Q3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Piyush Can u Check?

Comment: I've inlined the image

Comment: @Corion thank you. Now how can i do this ?

Comment: I have created map and drawer in this..i only neeed to overlay this with 4 imagebuttons. please do help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with this 4 images and set it to [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow)

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you. Can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: I'll Edit my answer.